# retrieve the url of the page an image sits on

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I'm trying to log URLs that access broken images, using an HTTP module to catch those images when accessed.

How do you retrieve the URL where that image sits on? is there a way to do it the other way round too? That is, loop through images served in a URL and decide which ones are broken.

This is all in ASP.NET with C#.

Comment: IIS already logs broken urls, not only this, you can set http-referrer enabled in order to log the url it was requested from. Can you tell why you want to redo when IIS already offers this inbuilt? Are you building your own file server?

Comment: You have a bug on your code and your image is upside down. :)

Comment: Akash: why? because i dont have access to the IIS serving the images (huge corporationg, limits imposed)
Aristos: Bugs are in the eyes of the beholder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to work out what page requested a broken image by checking the Http Referrer (`Request.UrlReferrer`) in your HTTP Module when you detect the 404.

Doing it the other way around would be much more complicated since you'd have to parse the outgoing HTML.